# Is Centering Data Around Their Medians in Least Absolute Deviation Regression Model (No Intercept), a Good Robust Practice For Smaller Data Sets?

Tags: regression, robust, centering, mad, least-absolute-deviations

Per the regression model:

$\mathbf{y} = f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{\beta}) + \mathbf{\epsilon}$

Where the $\beta$ estimate  of LAD regression is given by:

$ \hat{\beta}_{LAD} = \text{argmin}_{ b} \sum_{i=1}^n |y_i - f(\mathbf{b},x_i)|$

Now, some background, per Wikipedia on the topic of [Iteratively Reweighted Least Squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteratively_reweighted_least_squares), to quote:

> Iteratively reweighted least squares (IRLS) is used to solve certain optimization problems with objective functions of the form of a p-norm.

And further:

> IRLS is used to find the maximum likelihood estimates of a generalized linear model, and in robust regression to find an M-estimator, as a way of mitigating the influence of outliers in an otherwise normally-distributed data set, for example, by minimizing the least absolute errors rather than the least square errors. One of the advantages of IRLS over linear programming and convex programming is that it can be used with Gauss–Newton and Levenberg–Marquardt numerical algorithms.

I am particularly interested in applying the least absolute deviation (or LAD and also referenced as  ℓ1 norm) per an iterative least-square solution approach with weights equal to the respective reciprocal of the absolute value of the observed residues (or, more prudently, the max of some small value, like 0.0001, and the absolute value of the residue as created from the difference of actual observed and currently fitted per the centered data set). Interestingly, this recommended weighting scheme is noted in the Wikipedia cited reference, as equivalent to employing a Huber loss function in the context of robust estimation  (albeit, its use in the attached spreadsheet was not deemed apparently currently necessary).

Now, an issue I have with normally applied LAD regression arises, to quote from [Wikipedia on the topic of Least Absolute Deviations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_absolute_deviations):

> Checking all combinations of lines traversing any two (x,y) data points is another method of finding the least absolute deviations line. Since it is known that at least one least absolute deviations line traverses at least two data points…..

Or, I would restate per above, any possible arbitrary two data points in the data set, which may not be an intuitively best-suited alternative (as an intercept related to measures of a central tendency).

In particular, my suggested improvement to the art of applying LAD is, relating to, say, a two-parameter robust regression model, especially with a limited number of data points and especially perhaps some evident outlier presence, is, in a manner paralleling Least-Squares (that forces the intercept parameter through the mean of Y and X) is to reduce the dimensionality of the respective LAD regression, while also promoting robustness, along with being consistent with both an intuitive interpretation and possible prior expectation, by proscribing the respective LAD intercept passes through the median of Y and X, namely here Y_bar and X_bar. That is, substitute Y_bar - Beta*X_bar for the intercept term in the LAD regression model, which interestingly and more simply equates to transforming said Y and X by centering them around their respective medians, producing new centered variables Y’ and X’  in a no-intercept model. Further, dividing both Y’ and X’ by the square root of the first Least Squares’  one parameter regression model of Y’ versus X’ with starting weights of 1, results in two new variables Y’’ and X’’ whose simple one parameter regression produces a new Beta estimate. Using this Beta on X’ and subtracting Y’, forms a point residue that upon taking its absolute value, and square root and its respective residue whose reciprocal is used to again-transform X’ and Y’ to X” and Y” for the next step of simple one-parameter Least-Squares resulting in a new Beta. Repeat until sufficient convergent is achieved.

Note: One can construct (see the first cited Wikipedia reference for the iterative matrix approach) or employ your existing software package for higher dimension robust LAD regressions with several explanatory variables by simply using the median-centered data in a no-intercept standard LS regression model producing repeatedly new coefficients for all X-variables and their associated residues for weight determination and a new Beta (for a further iteration on transformed data per standard LS analysis or as an IRLS model, if available).

The above-described process is freely available for all as an illustrative two-parameter least absolute deviation regression model in a spreadsheet format [at this link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eNYm-p48oMAaeZ-ENjfDC_RiLJRutABncS3kH63df3w/edit?usp=sharing)S. Just change the data to observe the resulting robustness of the suggested median data-centered process which removes the intercept term. One can self-augment the analysis by also adding a normally (or other) distributed error term.

From a theoretical perspective, if one defines a variable Z = Y - Beta*X,  then the ℓ1-norm of Z minus its median, one has, by definition, the MAD (median absolute deviation) of Z, which is a cited known robust statistic, as is claimed (reference, see, for example,  [Wikipedia on “Median absolute deviation”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_absolute_deviation)).

The only argument I can envision against my median data-centered approach for more robust LAD regression is the very special case where one has particular knowledge of the regression’s intercept term (aka, when Y equals zero) that deviates from the assumed function of the associated medians.

Comment: Least squares does not "force" the intercept through the point of averages: that is a *consequence* of the statistical assumptions.  In LAD regression, the solution does not necessarily pass through the point of medians.  If you want to center the data with their medians for numerical stability in the calculations that would be fine, but forcing your solution to go through that point would be a novel and *different* procedure than LAD.  (I cannot tell from your description what you actually are doing and therefore cannot comment more specifically.)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I agree "forced" is not the correct word, more like apparently dictated per the LS math. I did not intend to invent a new "regression", but I agree, more akin to a MAD (Median Absolute Deviation) theme. I actually employed this path to address a real-world problem I am working on (per the log transform of the model Y= a*Exp(b*X).